# PHP Session variable defined by wrong variable

Tags: php, session, variables

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$id = 'dd';
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

When I go to this page the variable $_SESSION['id'] is defined as a number. But on this page I define the variable $id and then when I print the $_SESSION it has changed the variable $_SESSION['id'] to 'dd'. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only two ways for your code to work as stated:

1) You've got register_globals on, and your session already had a `id` parameter set

That means you're on an OLD php install, and/or a horribly badly configured one. Register_globals is pretty much the single greatest STUPIDITY in the history of PHP, and it has thankfully been eliminated from "modern" versions of PHP.

2) You created a reference beforehand, e.g.

```
$_SESSION['id'] = 'foo';
$id =& $_SESSION['id']; // $id now points at the session variable
echo $id; // prints foo
$id = 'bar'; // also changes the session value, because of the referencing.
echo $_SESSION['id']; // prints 'bar', because of the referencing.
```

Answer (score 2):

You have [register globals turned on](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php). This causes the declaration of `$id` to overwrite the `$_SESSION['id']` since they point to the same place.

You should turn this off as it is deprecated and can cause issues like you are experiencing.